# How to calculate the moving average without window function

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with calculating 5- and 10-day moving averages. I have these fields in my table: `Sno`, `date`, and `price`. Based on these I will get the 5- and 10-day moving averages. Below is the table.

(Please note that I am using an older version of MySQL, in which window functions are not supported.)

2 day average: it will be calculated at row no 3 as (row1+row2)/2, row 4 will be (row2+row3)/2 and so on..

4 day average: it will be calculated at row no 5 as (row1+row2+..+row4)/4, row 6 will be row2+row3+..+row5/4 and so on..

Final: Final is based on the below formula

```
IF(AND(D5>E5,D4<E4),"BUY",IF(AND(D5<E5,D4>E4),"SELL","HOLD"))
```

Example data:

```
Sno(A)  Date(B)      Close Price(C) 2 D_AVG(D)    4 D_AVG(E)   Final(F) 
1       01-01-13    2316.525        0             0
2       02-01-13    2304.89         0             0
3       05-01-13    2292.1825       2310.7075     0 
4       06-01-13    2279.67         2298.53625    0 
5       07-01-13    2267.8325       2285.92625    2298.316875   SELL
6       08-01-13    2254.735        2273.75125    2286.14375    HOLD
7       09-01-13    2129.906        2261.28375    2273.605      HOLD
8       12-01-13    2124.264        2192.3205     2233.035875   HOLD
9       13-01-13    2119.432        2127.085      2194.184375   HOLD
10      14-01-13    2114.34         2121.848      2157.08425    HOLD
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - although now might be a good time to upgrade

Comment: And I suggest that you pretend that the problem is about 3 day moving averages, for now